# Dynamicly adding paramteters to an ajax call based on a variables state

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have an ajax call that has a list of parameters that it needs to pass to its data object. But this list changes based on a certain category. So I'm trying to find a way to filter through the ones I need and the ones I don't need.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'......',
    type:'post',
    dataType:'json',
    data: {
        'api': 'myApilist',
        'address' : 'someaddress',
        'callTime' : _this.get('calltime'),
        'id1' : _this.get('id1'),
        'id2' : _this.get('id2'),
        'type' : _this.get('type'),
        'options': _this.get("options"),
        'mode' : _this.get('mode'),
        'time' : _this.get('time')
        'method' : 'POST'
    },
```

Sometimes `id1` and `id2` are not needed based on a state I have setup. So if the `state="time"` then the `id1` and `id2` don not need to be part of the data list. And if the `state="id"` then both ids need to be in there.

I was trying to use the filter loops in `_underscore` to try and filter out these options based on my state but it didn't work as I don't understand them correctly. How would I go about this.

`_this.get("options")` is referring to a Backbone model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build your data string before you pass it in the ajax call. This is one way you can do:

```
var dynData = new Object();
dynData.api = <value>;
dynData.address = <value>;
```

Looks static as of now. Now based on your 'state', you can add properties to the javascript object on the fly using the following:

```
dynData["newProperty"] = <value>;
```

Now using JSON and json2.js, you can create your JSON string using:

```
data:JSON.stringify(dynData);
```

Mark as answer if this worked :)

Comment: So I presume I can delete properties like. delete dynData.address

Comment: you can delete: delete dynData["propertyname"];